# Ctrl + Shift hotkeys no longer working?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Recently I've noticed (nearly, there's very few exceptions and they're seemingly random) all hotkeys that have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> no longer work. I've verified that it isn't the keyboard (tested 3 different keyboards including my laptops keyboard. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> also still work independently). I've found similar questions on superuser and one thing I found in common was Logitech gear (I have a Logitech G613 wireless mechanical keyboard and a Logitech G903 wireless mouse) although the answers to those questions (which usually were something about pressing a 'favourites' button?) don't work for me.

Another thing I noticed somethings the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> hotkeys just start working again. I don't know why this happens and it's seemingly random (and can take days or weeks). The problems have also persisted from one laptop to another (although I did keep the same boot drive 1TB NVME so I could keep all my programs).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? It's a big problem and messes with a lot of programs I use for university (some of the hotkeys that it breaks don't have alternatives so I straight up can no longer use them).

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: No it doesn't happen in safe mode

Comment: This looks like some installed program is eating up these keys. Try to track when is this happening, is it connected to one browser, having some product running in background etc. Which specific key combinations did you notice getting lost?

Comment: It's much easier to list which ones didn't get taken, which so far is Ctrl+Shift+Esc (task manager shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

As this does not happen when booting in Safe Mode, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for the problem.

Unfortunately, there is no way to identify the program that is hooking these
keys, so the only solution is to drill down by disabling startup items,
reboot, then repeat.

The tool to use is the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*.

You may start with the Logitech software, if you think it is connected.

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).